Creating dynamic (more advanced) grid in QGIS
I have a scenario with a grid that I just can't get right with the default "create grid" function. The desired grid output is as the following:

I would like to create a grid that has offset between each grid like this: the following grid is done by giving values to horizontal/vertical overlay; however, the polygon remains the same size as the original, and I have no way to perform self-difference so that I can get the polygon size I wanted.

One question per Question, please, as per the [Tour].

You're right. Apologies.

Please use the Picture button to insert any pictures into your questions.

Half the answer to your question is that you can:

Create lines in the shape that your polygons should be (Create grid tool).
Then create a polygon covering your entire zone of interest (Create grid tool).
Then split the polygon with lines using the Split with lines tool (twice).

If I understand your question correctly, you want empty spaces between polygons.
The second half of the answer is to delete any unnecessary polygons. By creating a selection and removing those unwanted polygons. This can be accomplished in a number of ways, such as with selection by location tool or selection by expression (every even/odd feature).




